# Printing translation table from Genbank with BioPython

Tags: python, biopython

I have a problem where I need to print the translation table from a Genbank file. My program looks like this:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
record = SeqIO.read("mycoplasma.gb","genbank")
print record.id
print record.description
print "Number of features:", len(record.features)
ct=0
for f in record.features:
    if f.type=="tRNA":
        ct+=1
print "There are ", ct, "tRNa features"

ct2 = 0
for f in record.features:
    if f.type == "gene":
        ct2+=1
print "Therea are", ct2, "gene features"

ct3 = 0
for f in record.features:
    if f.type == "CDS":
        ct3+=1
print "There are", ct3, "CDS features"

print "The following is feature 4:"
print record.features[4]
print "The following information is about feature 21:"
print "It is a", record.features[21].type, "feature"
print "Its location is", record.features[21].location
for feature in record.features[21]:
    print feature.qualifiers["transl_table"]
```

I just need the last part to print the translation table from the file.

Comment: Could you be more explicit about what the problem is that you need help with?

Answer (score 1):

It's easy. You first import the CodonTables with:

```
from Bio.Data import CodonTable
```

and after that you can get the CodonTables with the number in the Genbank files:

```
for feature in record.features:
    t_t = feature.qualifiers.get("transl_table")
        if t_t:
            print CodonTable.unambiguous_dna_by_id[int(t_t[0])]
```

Take note you need to get *an integer* to use `unambiguous_dna_by_id[]`, and `t_t` is most likely a list of strings like `['4']`